# jquery align to bottom inside div

Tags: jquery, css

Position absolute is out of the question. vertical-align: bottom; display: table-cell; would work BUT it needs to be centered too.

I need images inside div to be aligned to bottom. The images are different in height.

Should I just target each images and count the container height and use the remainer as top margin or is there easier solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is absolute positioning out of the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the 'line-height' and the 'text-align' properties of the div, and then set the 'vertical-align' property of the images inside the div.

i.e.

```
div.images
{
    width: 720px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 720px;
}
div.images img
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to position absolute relative to the entire page. You can just turn on the container's positioning to relative:

```
$("#my_id").parent().position(position : "relative");
```

and then position your element absolutely within

```
$("#my_id").position( position : "absolute", left : ______, top : ______ )
```

or in css,

```
#my_container {
  position: relative;
}

#my_id {
  position: absolute;
  left: __;
  top:  __;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the image as a background and use `bottom center` for positioning:

```
div {
    background: url("path_to_img") no-repeat bottom center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery for this:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="img/image.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

#wrap { position: relative; }
#wrap img {
    position: absolute; /* display: block is implied */
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Things are bit more complicated with this site and im sorry but css absolutes are off the question.

Ended up with this

$(".exhibition .thumb").each(function() {
   var h = $(this).height();
   var ih = $(this).children('img').height();
   $(this).children('img').css('marginTop', h-ih);
 
 });

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so the question can be considered complete